# Is there a way to compute permutations in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, comparison

I have multiple files (nearly 1000 of them) separated by space and I need to compute permutations with join function between each one of them using the second columns only. The important thing is that the comparison must not be repeated, that's why the permutation.

For instance, a small example with 3 files **A.txt B.txt** and **C.txt**

The general idea is to get **A B** comparison, **A C** and **B C**. *Neither **B A nor C A nor C B***

The 101 code would be

```
join -1 2 -2 2 A.txt B.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1 > AB.txt
join -1 2 -2 2 A.txt C.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1 > AC.txt
join -1 2 -2 2 B.txt C.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1 > BC.txt
```

Is there a way to accomplish this for thousand of files? I tried using a for loop, but toasted my brains out, and now I'm trying with a while loop. But I better get some orientation first.

Comment: consider updating the question with the `for` and `while` loop code you've tried; this may give us a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: So, you want to compare the first file with all others, then the second one with all others, except the first one, then... It's quite easy to implement but do you realize how many pairs it will produce? If you have 1000 files this will be 999 + 998 + ... + 1, that is, 999000 / 2 = 499500. Are sure sure this is what you want?

Comment: If you have `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`, what should the result be? Are you looking for _unique pairs_ in the set, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

As the number of iterations is quite large performance becomes an issue. Here is an optimized version of Matty's answer, using an array, to divide the number of iterations by 2 (half a million instead of a million) and to avoid a test:

```sh
declare -a files=( *.txt )
declare -i len=${#files[@]}
declare -i lenm1=$(( len - 1 ))
for (( i = 0; i < lenm1; i++ )); do
  a="${files[i]}"
  ab="${a%.txt}"
  for (( j = i + 1; j < len; j++ )); do
    b="${files[j]}"
    join -1 2 -2 2 "$a" "$b" | cut -d ' ' -f1 > "$ab$b"
  done
done
```

But consider that bash was not designed for such intensive tasks with half a million iterations. There might be a better (more efficient) way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: You'll get a performance improvement with `len=${#files[@]}` **before** the first lopo, and use `i < len - 1` and `j < len` as the loop conditions. Finding the length of an array is pretty expensive in bash.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, I edited my answer to incorporate your improvements, plus two minor ones (not 100% sure `len - 1` would be re-evaluated at each iteration of the outermost loop but precomputing it doesn't hurt...)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are after can be accomplished with two nested for loops and a lexicographic comparison to maintain alphabetical order?

```sh
# prints pairs of filenames
for f in dir/*; do
    for g in dir/*; do
        if [[ "$f" < "$g" ]]; then  # ensure alphabetical order
            echo $f $g
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's why you don't want to use bash for this:

First create 1000 files

```sh
seq 1000 | xargs touch
```

Now, distinct pairs with bash

```sh
time {
    files=(*)
    len=${#files[@]}
    for ((i=0; i<len-1; i++)); do
        a=${files[i]}
        for ((j=i+1; j<len; j++)); do
            b=${files[j]}
            echo "$a $b"
        done
    done >/dev/null
}
```

```
real    0m5.091s
user    0m4.818s
sys     0m0.262s
```

Versus, for example, the same in perl:

```sh
time {
    perl -e '
        opendir my $dh, ".";
        my @files = sort grep {$_ != "." && $_ != ".."} readdir $dh;
        closedir $dh;
        for (my $i = 0; $i < @files - 1; $i++) {
            my $a = $files[$i];
            for (my $j = $i + 1; $j < @files; $j++) {
                my $b = $files[$j];
                print "$a $b\n";
            }
        }
    ' > /dev/null 
}
```

```
real    0m0.131s
user    0m0.120s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Comment: So it's recommend it to do this sort of things rather in Perl or Python, they become more optimyzed

Comment: bash is slow. Shells are generally intended to glue the IO of external programs. bash has general purpose programming capabilities, but it's not a great language for complex calculations or data structures.